# mongodb nested array matching and sorting

Tags: mongodb

My json file looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57208fa10f80d14e9472942f"),
    "title": "How to stop hair loss?",
    "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 15:38:33 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    "status": "Active",
    "answer": [{
        "answerid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
        "text": "l eat protien",
        "imageurl": "http://leavesugar.jpg",
        "videourl": "http://leavesugar.mp4",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
            "name": "chetan kumar",
            "imageurl": "http://chetan.jpg",
            "followers": 150
        },
        "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:55:45 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "status": "Active",
        "comment": [{
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
            "posttext": "Most important is workout",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
                "name": "raju",
                "imageurl": "http://raju.jpg",
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:17:59 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }]
    }, {
        "answerid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
        "text": "WORKOUT 1 TO 2 HRS DAILY",
        "imageurl": "http://workout.jpg",
        "videourl": "http://workout.mp4",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
            "name": "Ram kumar",
            "imageurl": "http://ram.jpg",
        },
        "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:56:26 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "status": "Active",
        "comment": [{
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
            "posttext": "EAT MORE PROTIEN",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
                "name": "raju",
                "imageurl": "http://raju.jpg",
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:49:24 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }, {
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
            "posttext": "EAT PROTIEN AND WORKOUT DAILY",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                "name": "RAMU",
                "imageurl": "http://RAMU.jpg",
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:50:07 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }]
    }]
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("57204c194694965a19bac484"),
    "title": "How to loose weight?",
    "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 10:50:25 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    "status": "Active",
    "answer": [{
        "answerid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600b"),
        "text": "leave sugar and eat protien",
        "imageurl": "http://leavesugar.jpg",
        "videourl": "http://leavesugar.mp4",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
            "name": "chetan kumar",
            "imageurl": "http://chetan.jpg",
            "followers": 250
        },
        "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:55:45 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "status": "InActive",
        "comment": [{
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600b"),
            "posttext": "Most important is workout",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
                "name": "raju",
                "imageurl": "http://raju.jpg",
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:17:59 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }]
    }, {
        "answerid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
        "text": "WORKOUT 1 TO 2 HRS DAILY",
        "imageurl": "http://workout.jpg",
        "videourl": "http://workout.mp4",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
            "name": "Ram kumar",
            "imageurl": "http://ram.jpg",
        },
        "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:56:26 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "status": "Active",
        "comment": [{
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
            "posttext": "EAT MORE PROTIEN",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
                "name": "raju",
                "imageurl": "http://raju.jpg"
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:49:24 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }, {
            "commentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
            "parentid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
            "posttext": "EAT PROTIEN AND WORKOUT DAILY",
            "author": {
                "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                "name": "RAMU",
                "imageurl": "http://RAMU.jpg"
            },
            "postdatetime": "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:50:07 GMT+0530 (IST)"
        }]
    }, {
        "answerid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600d"),
        "text": "WORKOUT 1 TO 2 HRS DAILY",
        "imageurl": "http://workout.jpg",
        "videourl": "http://workout.mp4",
        "author": {
            "userid": ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
            "name": "Ram kumar",
            "imageurl": "http://ram.jpg"
        },
        "postdatetime": "Thu Apr 28 2016 10:35:38 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "status": "Active",
        "comment": []
    }]
}
```

I want to find out "status":"Active", "answer.status":"Active" and short 
 the answer according to their maximum no. of comment

I try this to find out only **"status"** and **"answer.status"** is active but it show the all result whose **"answer.status"** is Active or InActive

How to solve this issue please help me.

I used this aggregate to find out all "status" and "answer.status" :"Active"

```
db.QuestionAnswer.aggregate([{
            "$match" : {
                $and : [{
                        "status" : "Active"
                    }, {
                        "answer.status" : "Active"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]).pretty()
```

Comment: You need to use aggregation. There's an easy aggregation query if you are using mongodb 3.2

Comment: I use this db.QuestionAnswer.aggregate([{"$match":{$and:[{"status":"Active"},{"answer.status":"Active"}]}}]).pretty()

Comment: please provide expected document example

Comment: First i want only those data whose "status" : "Active" And "answer.status" :"Active" in above json file i used db.QuestionAnswer.aggregate([{"$match":{$and:[{"status":"Active"},{"answer.status":"Active"}]}}]).pretty()

Comment: Bt it show all data where "status":"Active" but doesn't show only those data whose "answer.status":"Active" it also so those file whose data "answer.status":"InActive".In above json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get only active answers please use query listed below:

```
db.aaa.aggregate([{
            $match : {
                status : "Active"
            }
        }, {
            $project : {
                _id : 1,
                title : 1,
                postdatetime : 1,
                status : 1,
                answer : {
                    $filter : {
                        input : "$answer",
                        as : "answe",
                        cond : {
                            $eq : ["$$answe.status", "Active"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

> output

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57208fa10f80d14e9472942f"),
    "title" : "How to stop hair loss?",
    "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 15:38:33 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    "status" : "Active",
    "answer" : [ 
        {
            "answerid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
            "text" : "l eat protien",
            "imageurl" : "http://leavesugar.jpg",
            "videourl" : "http://leavesugar.mp4",
            "author" : {
                "userid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
                "name" : "chetan kumar",
                "imageurl" : "http://chetan.jpg",
                "followers" : 150
            },
            "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:55:45 GMT+0530 (IST)",
            "status" : "Active",
            "comment" : [ 
                {
                    "commentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
                    "parentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
                    "posttext" : "Most important is workout",
                    "author" : {
                        "userid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600c"),
                        "name" : "raju",
                        "imageurl" : "http://raju.jpg"
                    },
                    "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:17:59 GMT+0530 (IST)"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "answerid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
            "text" : "WORKOUT 1 TO 2 HRS DAILY",
            "imageurl" : "http://workout.jpg",
            "videourl" : "http://workout.mp4",
            "author" : {
                "userid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600a"),
                "name" : "Ram kumar",
                "imageurl" : "http://ram.jpg"
            },
            "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 11:56:26 GMT+0530 (IST)",
            "status" : "Active",
            "comment" : [ 
                {
                    "commentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
                    "parentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                    "posttext" : "EAT MORE PROTIEN",
                    "author" : {
                        "userid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600e"),
                        "name" : "raju",
                        "imageurl" : "http://raju.jpg"
                    },
                    "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:49:24 GMT+0530 (IST)"
                }, 
                {
                    "commentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                    "parentid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                    "posttext" : "EAT PROTIEN AND WORKOUT DAILY",
                    "author" : {
                        "userid" : ObjectId("5719b83ffa86ca75d25b600f"),
                        "name" : "RAMU",
                        "imageurl" : "http://RAMU.jpg"
                    },
                    "postdatetime" : "Wed Apr 27 2016 12:50:07 GMT+0530 (IST)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out